# Custom appsettings.json is not loaded

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have an .net core 2.0 application, having multiple appsettings files. I have appsettings.json, appsettings.Development.json and a custom appsettings.Secure.json.

```js
//appSettings.json

{
  "AzureAd" : {
    "ClientId" : "CID"
  }
}

//appSettings.Development.json
{
  "AzureAd" : {
   "Random" : "random2"
 } 
}

//appSettings.Secure.json
{
  "AzureAd" : {
    "ClientSecret" : "CSECRET"
  }
}
```

I always want my appSettings.Secure.json configs to be loaded. Here's how the json files are configured.

```js
 var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appSettings.json", optional : false)
                .AddJsonFile("appSettings.Development.json")
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.Secure.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                .Build();
```

The problem is that my "AzureAd:ClientSecret" gets loaded in the config (gets listed in the Providers section of the config object) but when I inject IOption, the ClientSecret property is null.

AzureAdOptions is the class to which the properties are mapped, and it's registered as follows:

```js
services.Configure<AzureAdOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
```

Comment: not directly related, but: `I always want my appSettings.Secure.json configs to be loaded` - then why you specify it as `optional: true`? Flag it as required => at least you always will have an error when this file will not be available for reading

Comment: please show the definition of `AzureAdOptions` class

Comment: @Set public class AzureAdOptions
    {
        public string ClientId { get; set; }
        public string ClientSecret { get; set; }
        public string Instance { get; set; }
        public string Domain { get; set; }
        public string TenantId { get; set; }
        public string RedirectUrl { get; set; }
        public List<string> Permissions { get; set; }
    }

Answer (score 0):

JSON is not secure in any way, especially so considering that this is likely being committed to your source control.

The `appsettings.json` file is for generic, environment in-specific config. Then, you should have `appsettings.{environment}.json` files for each environment, but still no secrets should go in any of these files. In development, you can utilize User Secrets to store your secrets. In production, you should be using something like Azure Key Vault and/or environment variables for secrets.

Long and short, your `appsettings.Secure.json` file should not exist in the first place. It's not an environment and it's not secure.

Comment: We want an easy way to store secure settings. However, this file will not be stored in source control, so it is fine for us to save it like this. Still, any ideas how to do this?